# How to find and replace a specific word in string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, rdlc

I just want to replace a particular text with blank space in RDLC column.

I want to replace .aspx with `""` in every string.

I tried writing

```
=Replace(Fields!AuditsUserActivity.Value, ".aspx", "")
```

it works for this kinda lines

```
Page Applicants.aspx viewed
```

but not for these kinda lines:

```
Data added in Inspectors.aspx
```

i.e. it removed .aspx from those lines in which .aspx appears in in-between but not for those in which .aspx appears at the end of string.

WHY ?

Update:

I used this but not working

```
=Replace(Fields!AuditsUserActivity.Value, "@"+".aspx", string.Empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple code:

```
string result = Regex.Replace("x.aspx", @"\b.aspx\b", string.Empty);
```

Comment: thanks a lot but the code is inside RDLC column and Regex isn't working in it.

Comment: So you can use Replace method in srting

Comment: i tried but expression inside RDLC column is not showng Replace method inside string,

Comment: I tried simple Replace but that doesn't work with @ sign

Answer (score 0):

```
string inpString = "abcdeggggy.aspx"; 
string i = Regex.Replace(inpString ,@".aspx", "").Trim();
```

dont forget add using System.Text.RegularExpressions; namespace

Comment: One bracket is missing!

Comment: thanks a lot but the code is inside RDLC column and Regex isn't working in it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 string sResult= System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("abc.aspx", @".aspx", "");
```

Comment: thanks a lot but the code is inside RDLC column and Regex isn't working

Comment: inside RDLC i have to set expression for this

Comment: I used this in RDLC expression 
=Replace(Fields!AuditsUserActivity.Value, "@"+".aspx", string.Empty)

but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Like many others have suggested, you should try using a regex expression. Perhaps try copying this exactly:

```
=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Fields!AuditsUserActivity.Value, ".aspx", "");
```