# Why my code fails to replace a string with empty string in RDLC column expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, rdlc

I just want to replace a particular text with blank space in **RDLC** column.

I want to replace *.aspx* with `""` in every string.

I tried writing

```
=Replace(Fields!AuditsUserActivity.Value, ".aspx", "")
```

it works this kinda lines

> Page Applicants.aspx viewed

but not for these kinda lines:

> Data added in Inspectors.aspx

i.e. it removed '.aspx' from those lines in which .aspx appears in in-between but not for those in which '.aspx' appears at the end of string. Does someone know why?

*Update:*

I used this but not working

```
=Replace(Fields!AuditsUserActivity.Value, "@"+".aspx", string.Empty)
```

Comment: can you tell us what `Fields!AuditsUserActivity.Value` is equal to plz? could be a slight difference in what you are expecting. (step through with breakpoint on the line of code above and hover over `Fields!AuditsUserActivity.Value`.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find and replace a specific word in string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33408066/how-to-find-and-replace-a-specific-word-in-string)